# point CNAME record to A record

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, cname

On my domain example.com, I want to have a generic subdomain test.example.com that point to the folder test, and various cname (es. bar.example.com, foo.example.com) that all points to test.example.com.

I'm using Hetzner as provider, I created an A record (test.example.com) and a CNAME (bar.example.com) that point on the A record, and to make it works I had to add bar.example.com as an addon domain on Hetzner.

Any suggestion? Any possible solution that doesn't involve adding cname to addon domain?

Comment: Why don't you want to use an add-on domain?   Any solution is going to involve configuring the webserver.  You can't point to the server and choose the document root directory just through DNS.   Add-on domains are typically the way to configure shared hosting to set the document root for a subdomain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller for many reason, like limited addon domain slot. Also I want this process to be automatic, I can create cname with godaddy api, but i haven't api to create a subdomain each time, so it's annoying to do manually each time

Comment: Would you consider getting a VPS instead of using shared hosting?   It would be pretty easy if you had full control over your own server.  I don't think that implementing it on shared hosting without using add-on domains would work.

Comment: If it is a cpanel server, why not add it as an alias if it is simply pointing to an existing subdomain

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the limits if your provider, but from a technology POV -

Instrad if adding individual CNAMES you can use a wildcard for all subdomains - normally depicted as "*" in DNS servers (ie create *.example.com".  I would recommend you use an A record rather then a CNAME because CNAMES re misunderstood.

Nothing you do on DNS can provide a redirect on a web server because any DNS mechanisms used for http are resolved to an IP address by the client and a connection is made to the IP by the server.  The client then sends a header to the server advising what domain it is wanting content for.

This means that the server needs to "route" the request as appropriate - so to have the same answer for all subdomains the server needs to recignise them - usually this is done by a default host in the server config - something you likely wont have control of shared hosting.